# Ruby on Rails add new line between two #{string}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, line, addition, between

I've a text attribute for a model named `:settore_scientifico_progetto` and three string attributes, `:macrocat`, `:cat`, `:microcat`:

```
class Modulo1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_settore_scientifico_progetto
  before_update :update_settore_scientifico_progetto

  private      
  def set_settore_scientifico_progetto
    self.settore_scientifico_progetto = "#{macrocat}\n#{cat}\n#{microcat}" 
  end

  def update_settore_scientifico_progetto
    self.settore_scientifico_progetto = "#{macrocat}\n#{cat}\n#{microcat}"
  end
```

I'd like to put a new line where I typed `\n` but the code I posted gives me the output
`macrocat cat microcat`.

I would like it as follows:

> macrocat
>   cat
>   microcat

The output is shown in `show.html.erb`:

```
<div class="form-field">  
  <h3>Settore scientifico:</h3>
  <p><%= @modulo1.settore_scientifico_progetto %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where and how are you outputting the value?

Comment: Are you printing these values in a View? Try replacing `\n` with `<br />`.

Comment: settore_scientifico_progetto is a text field. I show it in a show.html.erb file of my app

Comment: You cannot have new lines in a text_field. Although you can use text_area for this.

Comment: @HarshGupta using <br/> in the output it print me macrocat<br/>cat<br/>microcat

Comment: I think `@modulo1.settore_scientifico_progetto.gsub("\n", "<br\>").html_safe`

Comment: you're righ @HarshGupta is a text_area but the attribute is not typed, it's builded from three strings that are typed.

Comment: thank you @PavelEvstigneev it works!!! thanks to everybody for your time!!

Comment: You should use Rails' built-in [`simple_format`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) helper instead of the `gsub...html_safe` method. `<%= simple_format @modulo1.settore_scientifico_progetto %>`. (This will automatically wrap the content in `<p>` tags; the linked documents show how to customize this.)

Comment: Just a side question, why do you have two methods that do the same thing?

Comment: @Iceman update and create? I don't know but when I update the model settore_scientifico_progetto without the update method nothing appen!

Comment: @tettoroberto I mean, the two methods do the same thing, and you could let before_update point to the same method as before_create

Comment: And also, do you need this in your db? Wouldn't it be better just to add a method that returns the desired string?

Comment: Yes I need this not only th string :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails has a helper specifically for this purpose called [`simple_format`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format).

```
<%= simple_format @modulo1.settore_scientifico_progetto %>
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
<p>macrocat<br/>
  cat<br/>
  microcat
</p>
```

Which is rendered by your browser like this:

> macrocat
>   cat
>   microcat

That seems to be exactly what you're looking for, and it takes care of sanitizing your HTML for you. (Options for customizing the output, e.g. changing the wrapping tag or HTML attributes, are [listed in the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format).)

P.S. Using the `gsub...html_safe` method advocated above is very risky. If your app accepts user input for any of the attributes you're printing, calling `html_safe` on those values means they won't be sanitized by ActionView and a malicious user could inject code into the view that makes your app vulnerable to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. [Here's a good primer](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3) on the ins and outs of `html_safe` in Rails.

Comment: I'll try in a few minutes this approach @Jordan!